# Primefaces Tooltip display of dataList

Tags: primefaces, tooltip

I have a hyper link, when I do a mouse hover on that link, The tooltip should populate a dataList ( Table of contents) .. is it possible to achieve with Primefaces tooltip ???

Comment: I think content exemple from: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tooltip.jsf can help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are no primefaces events on the p:tooltip component, but could solve your problem using JavaScript.

Example:

```
<h:form id="form">

<p:tooltip for="hyperLink" id="tooltip">
</p:tooltip>

<p:remoteCommand name="fireOnTooltip"
    action="#{bean.populateDataList}" update="dataList" />
</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("[id='form:hyperLink']").on("mouseover", function() { fireOnTooltip(); });
</script>
```